# Laravel 5.5 Blade Directive and Localization Not Working Together

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-blade

I am attempting to create a blade directive that will take a parameter and

1. Look up the translation
2. Capitalize the result

I've made several versions of this directive but with all of them that do not result in an error, I typically see only the uppercase version of the text that I passed.

**Version 1 (tried with and without the {})**

```
    Blade::directive('up', function ($expression) {
        $x = trans($expression);
        $y = strtoupper($x);
        return "<?php $y; ?>";
    });
```

**Another version**

```
    Blade::directive('up', function ($expression) {
        $x = trans($expression);
        return "<?php strtoupper({$x}); ?>";
    });
```

I have, for now, inserted a php block in my blade file verifying that my trans() lookups are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you aren't using `__('messages.welcome')` (underscore-underscore-function)?

Maybe this should work:

```
Blade::directive('up', function ($expression) {
    return echo strtoupper(__($expression));
});
```

Or do it this way in the frontend:

```
{{ @up(__('translation.string')) }}
```

And have this directive:

```
Blade::directive('up', function ($expression) {
    return echo strtoupper($expression);
});
```

In my opinion, this is fine in blade too:

```
{{ strtoupper(__('translation.string')) }}
```

Comment: I tried all of the above options and only this one worked.   
{{ strtoupper(__('translation.string')) }}

Thank you.  But I am still confused as to why the original attempt (with trans() which is described in Laravel's documentation) and such wouldn't work.

Comment: not working for me ... Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: syntax error, unexpected token &quot;&gt;&quot;